# converting Unicode CString (wchar_t) to const char * in a method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, unicode

In my Unicode, Visual Studio 2013 project, I am trying to use this method from an [API](http://www.galil.com/sw/pub/all/doc/gclib/html/gclib_8h.html#aef4aec8a85630eed029b7a46aea7db54):

```
... GOpen (GCStringIn address, GCon *g)
```

where

```
typedef const char *    GCStringIn
//C-string input to the library. Implies null-termination.
```

If I call the method like this, GOpen succeeds:

```
const CString connect = L"COM4 --baud 19200 --direct";
CT2A ascii(connect);
GOpen(ascii, &g);
```

But if I call like this, GOpen fails:

```
const CString connect = L"COM4 --baud 19200 --direct";
GOpen(getCharPointer(connect), &g);

...

const char * getCharPointer(const CString &cstr)
{
    CT2A ascii(cstr);
    return ascii;
}
```

What am I doing wrong that causes the string returned from getCharPointer method to not work with GOpen, and how can I fix it so I can do this conversion in a method?

Comment: You are trying to return something that references a variable which is local to the `getCharPointer` function.

Comment: Don't use `char*` or `CString*`, use `std::string`.

Comment: To elaborate, change `getCharPointer()` to return a `std::string` instead of a `char*`, then use `getCharPointer(connect).c_str()` when calling `GOpen()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 const char * getCharPointer(const CString &cstr)
```

When you write code like this, ask yourself: well this function seems to return a pointer. What will it point to? Is this memory static or allocated on the free store? If the former, what is the size of that static area? If the latter, where exactly in the code is it allocated and where is it freed?

If you cannot answer these questions, you need to spend some more time at the drawing board.

`std::string` has none of these problems. Always use `std::string`. When you need to pass a `char*` down to a C-style function, do it like this:

```
c_style_function(std_string_expression.c_str());
```

Never try to hold on the `char*` pointer returned from `c_str()` longer than needed.

In this particular case you can also try this:

```
GOpen(CT2A(connect), &g);
```

If you are literally doing what you have posted, consider doing this instead

```
GOpen("COM4 --baud 19200 --direct", &g);
```

Answer (score 2):

`CT2A` is a class that holds a `char*`.  `CT2A`'s destructor frees the memory that `char*` points to.  So by the time `getCharPointer()` returns, the pointer it returned is pointing to invalid memory.  You'll need to copy the string pointed to by `ascii` into memory you own.  The easiest way to do that would probably be to return a `std::string` instead of a raw `char*`, then you can use the `std::string::c_str()` method to pass that to `GOpen()`.